# pandas MERGE giving KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 Dataframes `df_general` and `df_award` which share a column called `ProjectNumber`. I want to merge them.

I tried dropping all the rows using dropna() and it did drop them-

```
df_award['ProjectNumber'].replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_award.dropna(subset=['ProjectNumber'], inplace=True)
df_award.head()
```

And then merged the 2 Dataframes like so (since I only want 1 column from first table and 2 columns from the second table)-

```
intersect = df_general[['Agency']].merge(df_award[['ProjectNumber', 'awarded_to']], on='ProjectNumber', how='left')
```

But I'm still getting a KeyError-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'ProjectNumber'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have almost everything right. The key needs to be in both the left and right side. It appears you aren't passing `ProjectNumber` on the `df_general` dataframe. Perhaps the following would work better:

```
df_general[['Agency', 'ProjectNumber']].merge(df_award[['ProjectNumber', 'awarded_to']], on='ProjectNumber', how='left')
```

Then you could simply drop the duplicate key column on the `intersect` dataframe.

Alternatively, if the key columns are named differently, you should specify `left_on=` and `right_on=`, while ensuring the left and right dataframes both contain the key.

Answer (score 1):

Your left dataframe in your merge statement is `df_general[['Agency']]`. This means it will be a single column dataframe (with only the column `Agency`), but you are trying to merge it one the column `ProjectNumber`. So I think you want to include that column as well so that that column exists in both frames:

```
intersect = df_general[['ProjectNumber','Agency']].merge(df_award[['ProjectNumber', 'awarded_to']], on='ProjectNumber', how='left')
```

Comment: A single column is a subset of the data frame, and the data formats are different.